# PC Version of "Easy on the Eyes" Display

Tags: windows-10, display

On my mac, there was a setting for the display called "Easy on the Eyes." I believe it dulled some of the colored, or yellow-ed the white. I'm not completely sure, though.

Is there a comparable setting in Windows 10?

Comment: If the settings was part of the operating system, no, its not compatible.  If it was a feature of the monitor, then the feature is OS independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Flux](https://justgetflux.com/):

> Ever notice how people texting at night have that eerie blue glow?
>
> Or wake up ready to write down the Next Great Idea, and get blinded by your computer screen?
>
> During the day, computer screens look good—they're designed to look like the sun. But, at 9PM, 10PM, or 3AM, you probably shouldn't be looking at the sun.
>
> f.lux fixes this: it makes the color of your computer's display adapt to the time of day, warm at night and like sunlight during the day.
>
> It's even possible that you're staying up too late because of your computer. You could use f.lux because it makes you sleep better, or you could just use it just because it makes your computer look better.

Microsoft is [also working on integrating their own built-in version of Flux into Windows 10](https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-working-integrating-flux-like-feature-windows-10/).

[Iris](https://iristech.co/) and [Sunset Screen](http://www.skytopia.com/software/sunsetscreen/) also exist, but I've had experience with neither of them.

Comment: I didn't love flux on my mac. How have you found it on the PC?

Comment: I've found it easy-to-use and had very few usability problems with it -- I'd give it another try and see what your experience with it on Windows is.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. Just going to wait a little while to accept this answer, to see what other people say.

Comment: I've updated the answer with two more alternatives, but I'd still suggest giving Flux a shot.

Comment: Did you find the alternative you were looking for?